# issue contract instance with front end

Tags: web3js, truffle, javascript, ganache

I compile and run my contract successfuly and connect my metamask to ganache but the problem is an error shows in consol TruffleContract not defind i guess the problem is in my way to get instance in my function initSupplyChain is incompatible with the versions i m used ,   im using truffle v5.3.11  and web3@1.4.0 and i update file web3.min.js to tha lastast version
this is my client side code:

```
App = {
web3Provider: null,
contracts: {},

 initWeb3: async function () {
    /// Find or Inject Web3 Provider
    /// Modern dapp browsers...
    if (window.ethereum) {
        App.web3Provider = window.ethereum;
        try {
            // Request account access
            await window.ethereum.enable();
        } catch (error) {
            // User denied account access...
            console.error("User denied account access")
        }
    }
    // Legacy dapp browsers...
    else if (window.web3) {
        App.web3Provider = window.web3.currentProvider;
    }
    // If no injected web3 instance is detected, fall back to Ganache
    else {
        App.web3Provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:7545');
    }
  App.getMetaskAccountID();

    return App.initSupplyChain();
},

getMetaskAccountID: function () {
    web3 = new Web3(App.web3Provider);

    // Retrieving accounts
    web3.eth.getAccounts(function (err, res) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error:', err);
            return;
        }
        console.log('getMetaskID:', res);
        App.metamaskAccountID = res[0];

    })
},


initSupplyChain: function () {
    /// Source the truffle compiled smart contracts
    var jsonSupplyChain = '../../build/contracts/SupplyChain.json';

    /// JSONfy the smart contracts
    $.getJSON(jsonSupplyChain, function (data) {
        console.log('data', data);
        var SupplyChainArtifact = data;
        App.contracts.SupplyChain = TruffleContract(SupplyChainArtifact);
        App.contracts.SupplyChain.setProvider(App.web3Provider);

        App.fetchItemBufferOne();
        App.fetchItemBufferTwo();
        App.fetchEvents();

    });

    return App.bindEvents();
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a bad version of truffle contract js file.
What you need to do is add the new version via CDN or form the node_modules in your index.html file.

first you should install `@truffle/contract` : `npm install -s @truffle/contract`

second, go to your index.html file and add the js file like follows :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./node_modules/@truffle/contract/dist/truffle-contract.js"></script>
```

this should alleviate that error. If you want to know, this is a problem with old truffle version and newer web3.js version not being compatible.

Comment: @KakiMsterOfTme  thank you  , it worked perfectly fine